# login using iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

**Problem:** My client wants to login to the email client directly from the website,i am using an `ifarme` to open the mail client in the website but when i try to log in it stops at loading.

**Question:** Is there any way i can log in to the email client from the website using `iFrame` or something.

**Code:**

```
<iframe src="http://mail.xxxxxx.com" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
```

If you guys have some time please try logging in with this credentials **UserName:test Pass:12345**

**Update** it works fine when i try it in Chrome or IE but gets stuck at Loading when using Mozilla...why??

Comment: what's the error that you get?, any javascript error? check with the hosting and ask for the login log for example...

Comment: i do not get any error...it stops at loading"SmarterMail Loading"

Comment: @balexandre If you have some time please try logging in with this credentials **UserName:test Pass:12345**

Comment: I did, there's plenty of javascript errors on the SmarterMail side, you could easily **see the console** for that. Because of that errors, SmarterMail  stops loading stuff. I did got to the setup screen thorugh, but errors start to popup when you finish the setup. Try: http://jsbin.com/ukinag/ and open the inspector for it.

Comment: hmmmm...whats the solution?? is there any way i open the mail client in another tab ,but dynamically add user name an password and also log in dynamically without user interactivity?? i mean the end user will enter the log in credentials in the website and we will programmatic ally log in to the client in another tab .

Comment: why dont they simple use the "remember me" function? and you simple open that page in a new tab?

Comment: @balexandre you know JackASS clients :( :P ...so what do you think ?? is there any way i can get this working??